# Removing Custom Permalink Structure for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I'm using a custom permalink structure for posts, which is domain.com/blog/%postname%/. However, I have a custom post type called 'events', and I don't want to use the default custom permalink structure for this custom post type, as domain.com/blog/events/ doesn't make sense. I want to just use domain.com/events. How can I override the custom permalink structure for a custom post type? I've found plugins that will allow you to set a custom permalink structure specifically for custom post types, but they won't allow me to remove the base permalink structure, only extend it.

Comment: what is the value of `with_front` in your post type registration code?

Comment: You have a multisite installation right? Try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-blog-slug/

Comment: Thank you, with_front was the key. I just had to set that to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `with_front` to `false` solved the issue.